# How to create shape Kendo Grid (toolbar Create)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to build its shape "Create" editing_popup? To add the field Upload File.

```
qwe.floorPlanGrid = $("#divCreateFloorPlanWindowGrid").kendoGrid({
        pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "NAMEKZ", title: "Қазақша аталуы" },
            { field: "NAMERU", title: "Наименование на русском", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
            { field: "STOREDFILENAME_INFO", title: "Имя схемы", width: "120px" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
        editable: "popup"
    }).getKendoGrid();
```